# AWS-sdk no paginators for rds cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagination, aws-sdk, amazon-rds, aws-sdk-go

I just found out that I can get a max of 100 records for `DBClusterSnapshots`, luckily `AWS` supports pagination where you can get a list by page. I was going over the documentation for `aws-sdk-go` to see how my Operation implements pagination. Unfortunately there isn't a pagination method for my Operation.

This is the operation I want to paginate. It says in the doc that it supports pagination.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-cluster-snapshots.html

However the pagination method for my operation doesn't appear to be supported

- doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/rds/

It only supports `DBSnapshotsPages` but not `DBClusterSnapshotsPages`
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS SDK for Go has the [DescribeDBClusterSnapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/rds/#RDS.DescribeDBClusterSnapshots) function:

```
func (c *RDS) DescribeDBClusterSnapshots(input *DescribeDBClusterSnapshotsInput) (*DescribeDBClusterSnapshotsOutput, error)
```

It accepts a parameter of [`DescribeDBClusterSnapshotsInput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/rds/#DescribeDBClusterSnapshotsInput), which includes:

> **Marker *string `type:"string"`**
>
> An optional pagination token provided by a previous DescribeDBClusterSnapshots request. If this parameter is specified, the response includes only records beyond the marker, up to the value specified by MaxRecords.

Therefore, your code can call `DescribeDBClusterSnapshots`, store the `marker` that is returned, then make another call to `DescribeDBClusterSnapshots`, passing in that value for `marker`. This will return the next 'page' of results.

Answer (score 0):

On aws sdk you can handle pagination by yourself using the response's `next_page` method to verify there's no pages to retrieve. In order to retrieve the next page of results, attaching some ruby example:

```
# object initializtion:
rds_client = Aws::RDS::Client.new

# implementation:
def self.describe_all_db_snapshots(db_instance_identifier: db_instance_identifier)
  response = rds_client.describe_db_snapshots({
                   db_instance_identifier: db_instance_identifier,
                   snapshot_type: "automated",
                   include_shared: false,
                   include_public: false,
                   max_records: 100 })

   while response.next_page? do

     # use the response data here...
     puts #{response}
     
     # next pagination iterator
     response = response.next_page
     
   end        
 end
```

For more details read aws sdk [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/RDS.html).